# AutoLayout and CATextLayer iOS7

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, interface-builder, autolayout

I'm trying to animate text changing with CATextLayer.

```
   intValueLayer = [CATextLayer layer];
   [intValueLayer setFrame:self.lblIntPart.bounds];
   [[self.lblIntPart layer] addSublayer:intValueLayer];
```

I'm using AutoLayout on my view and I know that setFrame method not working properly. In my case frame of CATextLayer smaller than self.lblIntPart .So, how can I add constraints to my TextLayer or display it with the same frame as self.llbIntPart.

Thank you!

All method looks like:

```
   intValueLayer = [CATextLayer layer];
    [intValueLayer setFrame:self.lblIntPart.bounds];
    [[self.lblIntPart layer] addSublayer:intValueLayer];

    [intValueLayer setAlignmentMode:@"center"];
    [intValueLayer setForegroundColor:self.category.colour.colour.CGColor];
    [intValueLayer setFont:CFBridgingRetain(@"DilleniaUPCBold")];
    [intValueLayer setFontSize:96.0f * scale];
    intValueLayer.contentsScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].scale;

    [intValueLayer setString:@"0"];
```

Comment: what is the output of     NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(intValueLayer.frame));
    NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.lblIntPart.frame));
    NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.lblIntPart.bounds));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying to reproduce your issue, here is what I understand.

Probably your Label frame is big, and the default CATextLayer font properties don't fit the frame completely.

Try adjusting CATextLayer's properties.

```
[intValueLayer setFont:(__bridge CFTypeRef)([UIFont systemFontOfSize:17])];
[intValueLayer setFontSize:17];
```

so that it matches the properties if you had used label as is.

Comment: I used this methods but you code give me an idea that after editing width label by constraints, new font size 
`[intValueLayer setFontSize:96.0f * scale];` 
is wrong. For test I use another scale and now everything looks good.
Thank you